# How to write commands to a serial port using NodeJs?

Tags: python, node.js, serial-port, electron

Good day everyone,

I am having issues writing commands to a lock connected to a USB controller which is connected to the laptop port using NodeJs. I have successfully achieved this in python, but is having issues in nodejs.

The reason why I am converting to nodejs is because the entire application is written in nodejs and runs has a desktop app via electron, and opening/closing port is just a small component of it.

The python equivalent and which works fine

```
ser = serial.Serial()
        ser.baudrate = 38400 #Suggested rate in Southco documentation, both locks and program MUST be at same rate
        // COMPORT  is a variable that stores an integer such as 6
        ser.port = "COM{}".format(COMPORT) 
        ser.timeout = 10
        ser.open()
        command = "open1"
        #call the serial_connection() function
        ser.write(("%s\r\n"%command).encode('ascii')) #Southco locks receives and sends commands in ASCII
```

Now in NodeJs, I am using the library serialport and I am trying to achieve this via nodejs that runs under the electron app.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');

   var port = new SerialPort("COM6", {
        baudRate: 38400
    });

    port.on('open', function() {
        port.write(Buffer.from('open1', 'ascii'), function(err) {
            if (err) 
                return sendData(500, err.message);

            console.log('message written');
        });
    });
```

I know nodejs is able to interact with the port because when I run `serialport-list` in command prompt or when i run it within the code

```
SerialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
    ports.forEach(function(port) {
        console.log(port.comName, port.pnpId, port.manufacturer); // or console.log(port)
    });
});
```

it shows the port information. Hence, nodejs is able to read the port, and issue information about the specific port, but I cant seem to issue command succesfully to it. It seems to get execute since no error message is thrown and it does display message written in console, but the lock does not react, whereas with the python code the lock does react by opening or closing demanding on the command that is written.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to confirm the succesful port-read running either a pure nodeJS or using Electron?

Comment: yes when i run serialport-list on command prompt it does read the port and displays its information. or when I run it within the code and launch the  electron app it does display information about so yes I can confirm the successful port-read.     However, and whats strange is when it does send the command it says message has been written but nothing actually happens port.on

Comment: Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to debug from within the serial-port library or post an issue to their github repository.

Comment: okay. How could i run my python serial script within nodejs since sending command to python serials works well and the lock open/close based on the command sent?

Comment: You can look into ShellJS, the exec/spawn commands allow you to launch external scripts (http://documentup.com/shelljs/shelljs)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am running this on windows, and not a unix device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128751/discussion-between-jens-habegger-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the SerialPort docs you'll see that the port is immediately opened when a new instance is instantiated, unless you pass the option AutoOn=false.
So, in your case, the port is already open by the time you set the listener .on('open'), so it never receives an event. Remove the listener and just call .write() immediately.