# How to run serialport once port is ready to receive the data?

Tags: node.js, serial-port, electron

Good day everyone,

I have the following code:

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');

  var port = new SerialPort("COM6", {
        baudRate: 38400
    });

port.on('open', function(data, callback) {
    port.write(Buffer.from('open1', 'ascii'), function(err) {
        if (err) 
            return sendData(500, err.message);

        port.drain(callback);
        console.log('message written');
    });
});
```

And I was wondering how I could run this code once the port is ready to receive commands so that i could open/close my lock.

For example, I feel that because the command is being sent immediately after its being open, nothing works because it doesn't have time to react.

For instance, at this documentation it talks about using `drain` https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport#serialportwritedata-encoding-callback--boolean but I am not sure what to do.

This app is being run through electron, and I can confirm that its able to establish relationship between the port and nodejs since when i run serialport-list I am able to display the port connected, just that sending command is a bit of an issue,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write commands to a serial port using NodeJs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40731956/how-to-write-commands-to-a-serial-port-using-nodejs)

Comment: I feel like I am asking the question from a different angle?

Comment: In that case you should append your old question.